# C# Generating dynamic executable from project

Tags: c#

I wanna generate an exe file with some changes in code from another `C#` `exe`.
I know that can easy compile `.cs` single `class` using `CodeDom.Compiler`
The thing I want to know is how to compile a project with 'Resources', 'Settings', 'Forms' and other elements.

```
CSharpCodeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(CompilerParameters, sources[]);
```

So, the question is where can I add all resources, settings and form (`.resx`)?
And can I do it with `byte[]` streams. Without unpacking project's zip.

Sorry for bad English and mby stupid questions. I wish somebody will help me...

---

For Example: I have byte[] array of resource file 'pic.png' and I wanna attach it to compiled exe as embedded resource.

Comment: do you want to do this for i18n purposes?

Comment: I need it for randomize things in executeble. To make unique app generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should learn about the new compiler service provided by Microsoft in `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis` code name "Roslyn". 
Roslyn provides you the way to compile the code and everything on the fly including creating and compiling complete solution and projects in-memory.

I think what you're looking for can be achieved via Roslyn. See below sample:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var syntaxTree = SyntaxTree.ParseCompilationUnit(
@"using System;
using System.Resources;
namespace ResSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        { 
             ResourceManager resMan = new ResourceManager(""ResSample.Res1"", typeof(Program).Assembly);
             Console.WriteLine(resMan.GetString(""String1""));
        }
    }
}");
            var comp = Compilation.Create("ResTest.exe")
                                  .AddReferences(new AssemblyNameReference("mscorlib"))
                                  .AddSyntaxTrees(syntaxTree);
            var resourcePath = "ResSample.Res1.resources"; //Provide full path to resource file here
            var resourceDescription = new ResourceDescription(
                resourceName: "ResSample.Res1.resources",
                dataProvider: () => File.OpenRead(resourcePath),
                isPublic: false);
            var emitResult = comp.Emit(
                executableStream: File.Create("ResTest.exe"),
                manifestResources: new[] { resourceDescription });
            Debug.Assert(emitResult.Success);
        }
```

[Original Source here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/95b3583b-5522-4c3d-ac54-822396c30a8b/add-resources-to-compiled-assemblies-systemresourcesmissingmanifestresourceexception?forum=roslyn)

At line `dataProvider: () => File.OpenRead(resourcePath),` you can provide your own 'FileStream' like `() => return _myResourceStream)` for your resource file.

Comment: Thanks for help, I will make a research this days.

Comment: The provided sample is written with Beta version of Roslyn. There are few changes in the syntax of these methods. Checkout the latest working sample of compiling [here](http://www.cshandler.com/2015/10/compiling-c-60-code-using-roslyn.html).